ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE
This is displayed after I turn on the PC and there are two more ACPI errors. How can I solve this issue without using intremap=off as was suggested by AI?
ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [Store](20230331/dswexec-433)    
ACPI Error: Needed type[Reference] , found [integer]  
ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for Store  
ACPI Error: Aborting method _PR.CPUO.PDC to previous error AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE*


ACPI Error: Needed type[Reference] , found [integer], 2. ACPI Error: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for Store, 3. * ACPI Error : Aborting method _PR.CPUO.PDC to previous error  AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE*.
